# Getting an item with a # from an stdClass

Tags: php

When I do a `print_r($this->info->artist->image[4]);`, I get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [#text] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/68145708/AWOLNATION+PNG.png 
    [size] => mega
)
```

How do I get the `[#text]` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do:

```
$this->info->artist->image[4]->{'#text'};
```

Comment: what does the #text mean?

Comment: It's just the name of one of the object's properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->info->artist->image[4]->{'#text'};
```